# How can I use Simple Modal to scroll to the top of my page just before the modal launches?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm successfully using Simple Modal to launch a modal when a button is clicked, however, I want the page to scroll to the top first.  I tried placing an anchor tag at the top of the page and referencing it in my link using , but it didn't work.  The Simple Modal still worked, but it didn't scroll to the top of the page first.  Is there a way to edit the simple modal javascript to make it first scroll to the top of the page before the modal is opened?

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScript before you call your modal: `window.scrollTo(0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#options

```
$('#modalContent').modal({
    onOpen: function () {
        $('html, body').scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```